# Boundedness of Fredholm integral operator

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $k\in C([0,1]^2)$, Define $T_k:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ such that for $x\in C[0,1]$, defined by $(T_kx)(t)=\int_{0}^1k(t,s)x(s)ds$. I want to show that $T_k$ is bounded and calculate its operator norm. Is my following proof correct

By definition, $
|T_k|:=\sup\{||T_kx||_{\infty}\,\big|\,||x||_{\infty}\leq 1\}. 
$ Let $x\in C[0,1]$ with $||x||_\infty\leq 1$, so $\sup\limits_{s\in[0,1]}|x(s)|\leq 1$. Then $$||T_k x||_{\infty}=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\bigg|\int_{0}^1 k(t,s)x(s)ds\bigg|\leq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(t,s)|\,|x(s)|\,ds\leq||x||_\infty\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(t,s)|\,ds\leq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(t,s)|\,ds.$$
It follows that $$|T_k|\leq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^1|k(t,s)|\,ds.$$
Let $\epsilon>0$ and define for all $t\in[0,1]$ $x_\epsilon:[0,1]\to\mathbb{K}$ by $$x_\epsilon(s)=\frac{\overline{k(t,s)}}{|k(t,s)|+\epsilon}.$$ Then we remark that $x_\epsilon$ is continuous and $||x_\epsilon||_{\infty}\leq 1$. We see that
\begin{align*}
||T_k x_e||_{\infty}&=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\bigg|\int_{0}^{1}\frac{|k(t,s)|^2}{|k(t,s)|+\epsilon}\,ds\bigg|=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^1\frac{|k(t,s)|^2}{|k(t,s)|+\epsilon}\,ds\geq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^1\frac{|k(t,s)|^2-\epsilon^2}{|k(t,s)|+\epsilon}
,ds=\\&\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^1(|k(t,s)|-\epsilon)\,ds=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(t,s)|\,ds-\epsilon.
\end{align*}
We see that $$|T_k|\geq\sup\limits_{\epsilon>0}||T_kx_\epsilon||_\infty\geq\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^1|k(t,s)|\,ds.$$
Combining this with our previous estimate of $|T_k|$, we conclude that $|T_k|=\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}\int_{0}^{1}|k(t,s)|\,ds,$ which concludes our proof.

Comment: what  does the bar notation mean

Comment: Complex conjugate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose
$$
x_\epsilon(s) = \frac{\overline{k(t,s)}}{|k(t,s)|+\epsilon},
$$ the $t$ appearing in the expression should be predetermined and remain fixed in the following calculation. This is what you should fix in your argument. To make this point clear, let us write
$$
x_\epsilon(s) = \frac{\overline{k(t_0,s)}}{|k(t_0,s)|+\epsilon},
$$ for some $t_0\in [0,1].$ Then, we have
$$
\lVert T_k[x_\epsilon]\rVert_\infty \geq |T_k[x_\epsilon](t_0)| = ∫_0^1 \frac{|k(t_0,s)|^2}{|k(t_0,s)|+\epsilon}ds\geq ∫_0^1 |k(t_0,s)|ds-\epsilon.
$$ Accordingly, we can bound $\lVert T_k\rVert$ from below: since $\lVert x_\epsilon \rVert_\infty \leq 1$, we have
$$
\lVert T_k\rVert\geq \lVert T_k[x_\epsilon]\rVert_\infty\geq ∫_0^1 |k(t_0,s)|ds-\epsilon.
$$Since our choice of $t_0$ was $\textbf{arbitrary}$, by taking supremum over $t_0\in[0,1]$, we get
$$
\lVert T_k\rVert \geq \sup_{t_0\in [0,1]}∫_0^1 |k(t_0,s)|ds-\epsilon,
$$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Finally by taking $\epsilon \to 0$, we have
$$
\lVert T_k\rVert= \sup_{t\in [0,1]}∫_0^1 |k(t,s)|ds,
$$as desired.

Comment: A question concerning your answer, you fixed the $t_0$ when you defined $x_\epsilon$, but took afterwards the supremum over all $t_0$, but this estimate works for only 1 specific $t_0$ right?

Comment: Since our choice of $t_0$ was arbitrary, this bound can be strengthened to $\sup_{t_0\in [0,1]}∫_0^1 |k(t_o,s)|ds-\epsilon$. Does this make it clear?

Comment: Yes, Thank you :)

Comment: No wait, could you please elaborate it because I start to get lost in my head. We define a function $x_\epsilon$ for SOME $t_0$, then we find an estimate for $||T_kx_e||$. Now if we take the supremo over $t_0$, don't we change or function $x_e$ if we change $t_0$?

Comment: Oops, that was my silly mistake! The final estimate should have been about $\lVert T_k\rVert$ rather than $\lVert T_k[x_\epsilon] \rVert_\infty$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Isn't there a problem when $||x_\epsilon||=0$?

Comment: Well, there's a possibility that $\lVert x_\epsilon\rVert_\infty = 0$. But it can be handled easily. I've edited my answer.